# Asp.net Checkbox values not being retained in popup

Tags: asp.net

We have an asp:CheckBox within an asp:DataList that appears on a popup window. Problem - the checked property values of the asp:Checkbox are not being retained. (The checked property is always false.)

NOTE - On debugging, the Page_Load method is getting called.

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <div id="inline1">
        <div class="popupbox coupons"> 
            <asp:DataList...>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox id="chk1" runat="server"/>
                    <asp:ImageButton id="btn1" runat="server"/>
                </ItemTemplate>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what functionality do u have in Page_Load event? have u used !isPostBack there ?

Comment: Yes Karthik there is a !IsPostBack in the Page_Load event.

Comment: A JQuery colorbox popup is being invoked on "Edit button" click on the main page. On this popup i have a asp:DataList containing a asp:Checkbox. Now even if i check any of the checkboxes and the event handler eg for "Delete" button is called , the Checked value for all the checkboxes shows as false.